# How can I make a dotted arrow in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently trying to make a stepper in CSS. So far I did everything else but now I need to somehow make a dotted line with an arrow pointing to the right in the bottom e.g. top line:

[image]

This is my HTML layout:

```
<div class="step-connection-line-wrapper">
  <span class="step-connection-line-down"></span>
  <span class="step-connection-line-right"></span>
</div>
```

I first had the idea to use `border: 1px dotted;` but this looks awful and gives me sharp edges instead or rounded dots. The second problem is that the top/below border needs to resize when I make the browser smaller.

As you can see the horizontal border is sometimes at the top and sometimes at the bottom. For that I thought I can switch the order in the div:

```
<div class="step-connection-line-wrapper">
  <span class="step-connection-line-right"></span>
  <span class="step-connection-line-down"></span>
</div>
```

Had someone done this before and knows a smart way instead of creating multiple child elements representing one dot?

Comment: Use SVG.js library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CSS border-image property for custom dots

```css
#borderimg { 
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(border.png) 30 round;
}
```

If your requirement is as complex as the image above, you can check out libraries like [SVG.js](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/)

Answer (score 4):

A one element solution:

```css
.dot {
  --c:red;  /* color */
  --r:10px; /* circle size */
  --s:10px; /* space bettwen circles */
  
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:20px;
  position:relative;
  --g:radial-gradient(circle closest-side, var(--c) 85%,transparent);
  background:
    var(--g) calc(var(--s)/-2) 0/calc(var(--r) + var(--s)) var(--r) repeat-x,
    var(--g) 0 calc(var(--s)/-2)/var(--r) calc(var(--r) + var(--s)) repeat-y;
}

.dot::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(var(--r)/2);
  left:100%;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  background:var(--c);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, 100% 50%,0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="dot"></div>
<div class="dot" style="transform:scaleY(-1);--c:green;width:150px;--r:5px;"></div>
<div class="dot" style="transform:scaleX(-1);--c:orange;height:50px;--s:15px;"></div>
<div class="dot" style="transform:scale(-1);--c:blue;width:80px;--s:5px;"></div>
```

[image: CSS dotted arrow]

Answer (score 1):

The only way im aware off that sort of works with purely CSS would be faking the dotted border with background-image and gradient. Like this you require one element for each line and for each arrow-head. The Positioning is possible using Flexbox. It is a bit of a hack and i personally would prefer the Solutions already offered  with SVG.js but it might be a possible solution.

Edit: forgot to mention: Sizes of the dots, arrowheads etc. are all adjustible by changing the border-sizes in the arrow tip and the gradient % and the background-size in the lines. The Arrows are resizing when you change the width / height of the Browser-window. You can test that in the full-page preview of the Snippet.

```css
.arrow {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 20vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.arrow-top {
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.arrow-top > .arrow-right{
  margin-bottom: -1vw;
}

.arrow-bottom > .arrow-right{
  margin-top: -1vw;
}
.arrow-bottom {
  flex-flow: row wrap-reverse;
}
  .arrow-right {
     display: flex;
      width: 100%;

      align-items: center;
  }
  .arrow-tip {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 1vw solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 1vw solid transparent;
    border-left: 2vw solid green;
  }
  .horizontal{
    width: 90%;
    height: 2px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%);
    background-position: bottom;
    background-size: 8px 8px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
  }

.vertical{
  height: 98%;
  width: 2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(black 25%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%);
  background-position: right;
  background-size: 8px 8px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

.spacer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow arrow-top">
  <div class="arrow-right">
    <div class="horizontal">
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-tip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vertical">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="spacer">
</div>
<div class="arrow arrow-bottom">
  <div class="arrow-right">
    <div class="horizontal">
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-tip">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vertical">
  </div>
</div>
```